# Get the contour (outline) from a png image with the correct edges

Tags: python, opencv, svg, polygon, contour

I have multiple png files and I'm trying to get the polygon contour coordinates.
That is the simplified coordinates, only each outer corner (not a convex hull polygon).

The program that will do this at the moment is python and opencv.
But another program is oke I did try to fix this using npm packages, imagemagick, potrace, Lua.
It will be uses as a shell command in a 'build polygons from images' process.

This was the last test under python.

The problem now is the that some edges are 'not' correct in the example below.

I did the following steps

- Convert the alpha to black and white
- Trace the contour
- Get the coordinates

1. The original png file contains black lines (keep them).

[image: Original png]

2. Converted black and white image (you can't see the top line, because this website have a white background)

```
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img[:, :, 3], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

[image: Converted png]

3. Traced contour outline (not the output I want)

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

[image: traced image]

The problem are the two holes, the 1 pixel left and 1 pixel right is missing.

[image: problem zoom detail]

4. When I use that contour data inside a other program you get this:

[image: external polygon]

5. I want this contour outline polygon data, so the external program show this:

[image: output I want]

```py
# https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac#what-to-do
# https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/10/21/install-opencv-python-macos/
# https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733694/process-image-to-find-external-contour
# https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823221/imagemagick-find-coordinates-of-outline-of-transparent-png-not-border

import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('../temp/bord.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# make black and white
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img[:, :, 3], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# find the external contour
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# at this point I want to have the correct contours to process them inside a other program
# print(contours)

# start debugging
#save image
cv2.imwrite('../temp/bord_converted.png',mask) 


#create an empty image for contours
img_contours = np.zeros(img.shape)
# draw the contours on the empty image
cv2.drawContours(img_contours, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 1)
cv2.imwrite('../temp/bord_contour.jpg',img_contours)
```

EDIT

The other things that I did try:

Marching squares programs

**Golang**

https://github.com/zx9597446/marchingsquare/issues/1
That one gives me another problem, but the correct codes

**Npm**
https://github.com/scottglz/image-outline
That one gives me almost the same problem as above

**imagemagick**

Was trying some things converting the png to black/ and white and return the outline.

```
convert "$IMAGE" -matte -bordercolor none -border 1 -alpha extract -edge 1 -threshold 50% -depth 8 txt: | awk -F: '/white/{print $1}'
```

**potrace**

But all the outputs have things so I can't use it.

```
potrace --progress -b svg --blacklevel 0 --turdsize 0 --longcurve --opttolerance 0 --unit 1 --turnpolicy white --alphamax 0 --scale 1 --group --flat ../temp/bordout.bmp -o ../temp/bordout.svg
potrace --progress -b eps -c --blacklevel 0 --turdsize 0 --longcurve --opttolerance 0 --unit 1 --turnpolicy white --alphamax 0 --scale 1 --flat ../temp/bordout.bmp -o ../temp/bordout.eps
potrace --progress -b pdf -c --blacklevel 0 --turdsize 0 --longcurve --opttolerance 0 --unit 1 --turnpolicy white --alphamax 0 --scale 1 --flat ../temp/bordout.bmp -o ../temp/bordout.pdf
potrace --progress -b pdfpage --blacklevel 0 --turdsize 0 --longcurve --opttolerance 0 --unit 1 --turnpolicy white --alphamax 0 --scale 1 --flat ../temp/bordout.bmp -o ../temp/bordout.pdfpage
potrace --progress -b ps -c --blacklevel 0 --turdsize 0 --longcurve --opttolerance 0 --unit 1 --turnpolicy white --alphamax 0 --scale 1 --flat ../temp/bordout.bmp -o ../temp/bordout.ps
potrace --progress -b pgm --blacklevel 0 --turdsize 0 --longcurve --opttolerance 0 --unit 1 --turnpolicy white --alphamax 0 --scale 1 --flat ../temp/bordout.bmp -o ../temp/bordout.pgm
potrace --progress -b dxf --blacklevel 0 --turdsize 0 --longcurve --opttolerance 0 --unit 1 --turnpolicy white --alphamax 0 --scale 1 --flat ../temp/bordout.bmp -o ../temp/bordout.dxf
potrace --progress -b geojson --blacklevel 0 --turdsize 0 --longcurve --opttolerance 0 --unit 1 --turnpolicy white --alphamax 0 --scale 1 --flat ../temp/bordout.bmp -o ../temp/bordout.geojson
potrace --progress -b gimppath --blacklevel 0 --turdsize 0 --longcurve --opttolerance 0 --unit 1 --turnpolicy white --alphamax 0 --scale 1 --flat ../temp/bordout.bmp -o ../temp/bordout.gimppath
potrace --progress -b xfig --blacklevel 0 --turdsize 0 --longcurve --opttolerance 0 --unit 1 --turnpolicy white --alphamax 0 --scale 1 --flat ../temp/bordout.bmp -o ../temp/bordout.xfig
```

For example the SVG output looks correct as a picture but I can't convert it to a x,y point array polygon.

```
<path d="M121 132 l-121 0 0 -66 0 -66 121 0 121 0 0 66 0 66 -121 0z m0 -1
l120 0 0 -22 0 -23 -10 0 -11 0 0 -42 0 -43 -5 0 -5 0 0 43 0 42 -89 0 -89 0
0 -42 0 -43 -5 0 -5 0 0 43 0 42 -10 0 -11 0 0 23 0 22 120 0z M121 130 l-119
0 0 -21 0 -22 11 0 10 0 0 -42 0 -43 4 0 4 0 0 43 0 42 90 0 90 0 0 -42 0 -43
4 0 4 0 0 43 0 42 11 0 10 0 0 22 0 21 -119 0z"/>
</g>
```

Using https://github.com/Phrogz/svg-path-to-polygons for example gives me

```
[
  [
    [ 121, 132 ], [ 0, 132 ],
    [ 0, 66 ],    [ 0, 0 ],
    [ 121, 0 ],   [ 242, 0 ],
    [ 242, 66 ],  [ 242, 132 ],
    [ 121, 132 ], [ 121, 132 ],
    closed: true
  ],
  [
    [ 121, 131 ], [ 241, 131 ], [ 241, 109 ],
    [ 241, 86 ],  [ 231, 86 ],  [ 220, 86 ],
    [ 220, 44 ],  [ 220, 1 ],   [ 215, 1 ],
    [ 210, 1 ],   [ 210, 44 ],  [ 210, 86 ],
    [ 121, 86 ],  [ 32, 86 ],   [ 32, 44 ],
    [ 32, 1 ],    [ 27, 1 ],    [ 22, 1 ],
    [ 22, 44 ],   [ 22, 86 ],   [ 12, 86 ],
    [ 1, 86 ],    [ 1, 109 ],   [ 1, 131 ],
    [ 121, 131 ], [ 121, 131 ], closed: true
  ],
  [
    [ 121, 130 ], [ 2, 130 ],   [ 2, 109 ],
    [ 2, 87 ],    [ 13, 87 ],   [ 23, 87 ],
    [ 23, 45 ],   [ 23, 2 ],    [ 27, 2 ],
    [ 31, 2 ],    [ 31, 45 ],   [ 31, 87 ],
    [ 121, 87 ],  [ 211, 87 ],  [ 211, 45 ],
    [ 211, 2 ],   [ 215, 2 ],   [ 219, 2 ],
    [ 219, 45 ],  [ 219, 87 ],  [ 230, 87 ],
    [ 240, 87 ],  [ 240, 109 ], [ 240, 130 ],
    [ 121, 130 ], [ 121, 130 ], closed: true
  ]
]
```

EDIT 2

When I use the SVG solution the output give me now a readable point list

```
<polygon fill="none" points="0,0 0,44 20,44 21,45 21,129 30,129 30,45 31,44 208,44 209,45 209,129 218,129 218,45 219,44 239,44 239,0" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="miter" />
```

But when I use that coordinate list it is not 100% correct.
The corners are still not correct.

The output (zoomed in) with firefox will show this:

[image: firefox output]

And the program where I will use the coordinate list (not the SVG)

```
love.graphics.polygon("line",0,0,0,44,20,44,21,45,21,129,30,129,30,45,31,44,208,44,209,45,209,129,218,129,218,45,219,44,239,44,239,0)
```

Will output:

[image: love2d output]

Edit 3

Using the last python script don't make the polygon.

[image: program output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Desired Output: Vector Graphic

The points, lines, and curves in a vector graph may be scaled up or down to any resolution with no aliasing. As such you will not see the broken corners. Suppose the output is a vector graph in SVG format. The corners can be visualized nicely by converting each contour to an SVG polygon. You may refer to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes) for three choices to render the corners. I also add a function `add_pixel_fillers` to adjust close enough points.

```py
import cv2
import svgwrite

img = cv2.imread("WFVso.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img[:, :, 3], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

def add_pixel_fillers(img, cnt):
    n_points = len(cnt)
    for idx in range(n_points):
        prev_pt = cnt[(idx+n_points+1) % n_points]
        next_pt = cnt[(idx+1) % n_points]
        if abs(cnt[idx][0]-next_pt[0])==1 and abs(cnt[idx][1]-next_pt[1])==1:
            temp_x, temp_y = max(cnt[idx][0], next_pt[0]), min(cnt[idx][1], next_pt[1])
            if img[temp_y, temp_x] == 255:
                cnt[idx][0] = temp_x
                cnt[idx][1] = temp_y
            else:
                temp_x, temp_y = min(cnt[idx][0], next_pt[0]), max(cnt[idx][1], next_pt[1])
                if img[temp_y, temp_x] == 255:
                    cnt[idx][0] = temp_x
                    cnt[idx][1] = temp_y
    return cnt

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

h, w = width=img.shape[0], img.shape[1]
dwg = svgwrite.Drawing('test.svg', height=h, width=w, viewBox=(f'-10 -10 {h} {w}'))
for cnt in contours:
    cnt = add_pixel_fillers(mask, cnt.squeeze().tolist())
    dwg.add(dwg.polygon(
        points=cnt,
        stroke_linecap='round',
        stroke='black',
        fill='none',
        stroke_linejoin='miter'
        ))
dwg.save()
```

The SVG output of the example input is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg baseProfile="full" height="100%" version="1.1" viewBox="-10 -10 130 240" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs />
<polygon fill="none" points="0,0 0,44 21,44 21,45 21,129 30,129 31,44 31,44 209,44 209,45 209,129 218,129 219,44 219,44 239,44 239,0" stroke="black" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="miter" />
</svg>
```

[image: Output Image]

### Desired Output: Raster Graphic

How to fill the missing pixels in the corners? Suppose you only need to handle corners at 90 degree in the given cases, there will only be a limited number of pixel patterns where you want to fill in the missing pixel. Given those paterns, you can use `ndimage.correlate` function in the scipy package to find out where to fill in the pixel.

Sample code

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
# Assume this is the contour you obtained in step 3
img = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

# You can add the patterns here
patterns = [
    np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0],
              [1,1,0,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,0]]),
    np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,1,1],
              [0,0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,0]])]

missing_corners = np.zeros_like(img) #Result will be stored here
for patt in patterns:
    result = ndimage.correlate(img, patt, mode="constant")
    corners = np.floor(result/np.sum(patt)).astype(int)
    missing_corners = (missing_corners + corners) % 2 #Can use binary OR
```

To see the result

```
print(missing_corners)
```

will show the locations of the missing corner:

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

For more complex shapes, I suggest you to generate vector drawings (e.g. SVG) using packages like `drawSvg` when you export the contours.

Comment: Thanks, but how to a merge the result into the contour ? I have many different images and don't like the idea by making many patterns. I did try a program potrace that output a  SVG, but I can't find a program to convert the SVG polygon path, to a coordinate path. I don't know why this is a difficult task, because I do know do alpha and the outline is the first solid pixel. When I turn them into x,y points , I have to convert them in clockwise coordinates order to create the polygon.

Comment: Would you mind including an example to show (here or the original post) why you cannot convert a coordinate path to an SVG polygon path? I think they are almost the same.

Comment: I have updated the solution. You may notice that the concerned angles are not sharp enough even in the SVG image. The problem comes from the thresholding step. In case you want to obtain very sharp angles, I suggest you apply contour approximation via cv2.approxPolyDP https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I did try to implement the cv2.approxPolyDP but that don't make any notable differents (maybe I do it wrong, inside the for loop). Could you edit your code so the coordinates contains the sharp angels (the output). Then your answer is 100% what I want ;)

Comment: OK. The solution is updated again. I think this is the best answer I can think of. Hope it help.

Comment: nah, see the last edit, the polygon is now broken in the other program. I guess I have to choose another road.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to update the SVG block. The Python code is correct though. Besides, if you try to draw the contours on paper, you can verify the points are correct. And my SVG viewer is Firefox which allows you to zoom in to see the thin lines. This is useful if your screen resolution is low.

Comment: If you want to display the outline in Love2D nicely, you should change the line width via love.graphics.setLineWidth(width).

Comment: The firefox output was correct !, The line width in love2d don't solve the problem but I will fix that, and for collision I don't need a visible line, only for debugging. Thanks !